# Bungee jumping: why does using the law of conservation of energy give me a different $k$ than solving for $k$ when the net force is 0?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, energy-conservation, harmonic-oscillator, spring

I tried solving the following problem:

> "A 62.0kg bungee jumper jumps from a bridge. She is tied to a bungee cord whose unstretched length is 12.0m and falls a total of 31m. Calculate the spring constant $k$ of the bungee cord."

I first tried to use the law of conservation of energy to solve the problem:

Gravitational Potential Energy before jumping = Potential Elastic Energy after falling the 31m.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Since the net force acting on the jumper is equal to 0 when she has fallen the 31m, I tried finding the same result solving for k:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see, both answers differ A LOT from each other. I would really appreciate if someone could clarify the reason why, or if I'm making any mistakes.

Comment: *"Since the net force acting on the jumper is equal to 0 when she has fallen the 31m"* - think more carefully about that. Question: at the bottom of her fall, where her velocity is (momentarily) zero, is the net force actually zero?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri thinking more about it, I guess not, since if it were zero the jumper would stay unaccelerated forever, wouldn't she?

Comment: You should post an answer to your own question, if you now can

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was assuming that the net force acting on the jumper was equal to 0 when she had fallen the 31m. Velocity at that moment is (momentarily) zero, but that doesn't mean net force is zero too, since she's accelerating and not in equilibrium.

Thanks to @AlfredCentauri for pointing it out!